# How do you select a struct based on a string in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, trait-objects, dynamic-dispatch

### Problem Statement

I have a set of structs, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, which all implement a trait
`Runnable`.

```rust
trait Runnable {
    fn run(&mut self);
}
impl Runnable for A {...}
impl Runnable for B {...}
impl Runnable for C {...}
impl Runnable for D {...}
```

I also have a struct `Config` which serves as the specification for constructing `A`,
`B`, `C`, and `D` instances.

```rust
struct Config {
    filename: String,
    other_stuff: u8,
}

impl From<Config> for A {...}
impl From<Config> for B {...}
impl From<Config> for C {...}
impl From<Config> for D {...}
```

In my program, I would like to parse a `Config` instance and construct either an `A`,
`B`, `C`, or `D` depending on the value of the `filename` field, and then call
`Runnable::run` on it. The struct should be selected by sequentially checking each struct against a `filename` string and selecting the first one that "matches" that string.

### Naïve Implementation

Here is a naïve implementation.

```rust
trait CheckFilename {
    fn check_filename(filename: &str) -> bool;
}
impl CheckFilename for A {...}
impl CheckFilename for B {...}
impl CheckFilename for C {...}
impl CheckFilename for D {...}


fn main() {
    let cfg: Config = get_config(); // Some abstract way of evaluating a Config at runtime.

    let mut job: Box<dyn Runnable> = if A::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
        println!("Found matching filename for A");
        Box::new(A::from(cfg))
    } else if B::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
        println!("Found matching filename for B");
        Box::new(B::from(cfg))
    } else if C::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
        println!("Found matching filename for C");
        Box::new(C::from(cfg))
    } else if D::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
        println!("Found matching filename for D");
        Box::new(D::from(cfg))
    } else {
        panic!("did not find matching pattern for filename {}", cfg.filename);
    };

    job.run();
}
```

This works but has some code smells:

- Giant `if else if else if else if else...` statement is smelly IMO
- Lots of repetition: The code used to check the filename, print which struct type was
  selected, and construct the instance from the config are the same for each branch and
  only differ in which struct type they're dealing with. Is there a way to abstract this
  repetition away?
- Very error prone: its very easy to accidentally screw up the mapping between filename
  string and struct by failing to synchronize the struct with the predicate; for
  example writing something like:

  ```rust
  if D::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
      println!("Found matching filename for D");
      Box::new(B::from(cfg)) // Developer error: constructs a B instead of a D.
  }
  ```

  and the compiler would not catch this.
- Adding new structs (e.g. `E`, `F`, `G`, etc.) to the program is not very ergonomic. It requires adding a new branch for each to the main `if else` statement. It'd be much nicer to simply add the struct to some sort of "master list" of srtuct types.

---

Is there a more elegant or idiomatic way of doing this that addresses these smells?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the conversion consumes `Config`, the challenge in unifying the logic for all types is that you need to conditionally move the config value in order to convert it.  The standard library has multiple cases of fallible consuming functions and the pattern they use is to return `Result`, handing back the maybe-consumed value in the `Err` case.  For example, [`Arc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap) extracts the inner value of an `Arc`, but if this fails it gives the `Arc` back in the `Err` variant.

We can do the same here, creating a single function that produces one of the appropriate structs if the filename matches, but giving back the config on an error:

```
fn try_convert_config_to<T>(config: Config) -> Result<Box<dyn Runnable>, Config>
where
    T: Runnable + CheckFilename + 'static,
    Config: Into<T>,
{
    if T::check_filename(&config.filename) {
        Ok(Box::new(config.into()))
    } else {
        Err(config)
    }
}
```

Then you can write another function with a static slice of specific instantiations of this function, and it can try each in order until one succeeds.  Since we move the config into each loader function, we have to put it back in the `Err` case so the next loop iteration can move it again.

```
fn try_convert_config(mut config: Config) -> Option<Box<dyn Runnable>> {
    static CONFIG_LOADERS: &[fn(Config) -> Result<Box<dyn Runnable>, Config>] = &[
        try_convert_config_to::<A>,
        try_convert_config_to::<B>,
        try_convert_config_to::<C>,
        try_convert_config_to::<D>,
    ];

    for loader in CONFIG_LOADERS {
        match loader(config) {
            Ok(c) => return Some(c),
            Err(c) => config = c,
        };
    }

    None
}
```

This solves all of your concerns:

- There is no longer a giant if-else chain, just a loop.
- The code duplication is gone because `try_convert_config_to` implements the logic for all types one time.
- It's impossible to accidentally invoke the two parts of the process (`check_filename` and `into`) on different types as long as you use `try_convert_config_to`.
- To add a new type you just need to add a new element to the `CONFIG_LOADERS` slice.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31bbecc83956ff38bb305b585f56723b))

Comment: Excellent solution. Can you explain why `T` needs the `'static` trait bound in `try_convert_config_to`?

Comment: @RBF06 Because `dyn Foo` implicitly has a `'static` bound unless you specify one, so `Box<dyn Runnable>` is equivalent to `Box<dyn Runnable + 'static>`. Therefore, for a `Box<T>` to be cast to a `Box<dyn Runnable>`, `T` must be `'static`.

Comment: To clarify, "unless you specify one" means "unless you specify a different lifetime." E.g. you can have `Box<dyn Runnable + 'a>` for some lifetime `'a`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to clean up a few minor loose ends left by the accepted answer, and also to provide some additional explanation and references. Shout out to @cdhowie for providing the accepted answer and the knowledge I needed to solve my problem.

---

### Overview

By refactoring a few things, it is possible to solve all the issues with the naïve
implementation. The trick is to create a simple fallible conversion function that
converts a `Config` value into a `Box<dyn Runnable>` if the filename matches, but
gives the `Config` value back in the `Err` variant if the filename does not match
so that the next specialization can try.

### Define the requirements

First, let us compile a list of the minimum requirements each type must satisfy in
order to support our application:

1. must be `Runnable` since we intend to `run()` it once instantiated.
2. must be `From<Config>` because we intend to create one from a `Config`
3. must have a name associated with it so we can print the log message identifying which
   type was selected.
4. must be able to determine if it "matches" a `filename` string

With these requirements defined, we define a Trait to enforce them:

```rust
trait Job: Runnable + From<Config> {
    const NAME: &'static str;
    fn check_filename(filename: &str) -> bool;
}
```

Requirement 1 and 2 are encoded using
[supertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait)
and requirement 3 is encoded using an [associated constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants)

Note: in the problem statement, this trait was named `CheckFilename` but it is renamed
here to `Job` because that seems more appropriate considering the additional
requirements.

Implementing `Job` for each of our structs is very straightforward:

```rust
impl Job for A {
    // This str will be the used as the name of the struct when printing the log message
    const NAME: &'static str = "A";
    fn check_filename(filename: &str) -> bool {
        // logic determining if a `str` matches a Job type goes here
        filename.starts_with('A')
    }
}
impl Job for B {...}
impl Job for C {...}
impl Job for D {...}
```

### Create a generic converter function

Next, we create a simple fallible function that tries to convert a `Config` value to
a `Box<dyn Runnable>`, but gives the `Config` value back (with ownership) if it doesn't
match. This function is generic over all `Job` types.

```rust
fn try_convert_config_to<T: Job + 'static>(cfg: Config) -> Result<Box<dyn Runnable>, Config> {
    if T::check_filename(&cfg.filename) {
        println!("Found matching job for filename `{}`: {}", cfg.filename, T::NAME);
        Ok(Box::<T>::new(cfg.into()))
    } else {
        Err(cfg)
    }
}
```

### Chain it all together

Finally, a (boxed) `Runnable` [trait
object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) can be
initialized by calling `try_convert_config_to::<A>` and sequentially passing error
values through a chain of `Result::or_else` with the remaining specializations of `Job`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let cfg: Config = get_config();
    let mut job: Box<dyn Runnable> = try_convert_config_to::<A>(cfg)
        .or_else(try_convert_config_to::<B>)
        .or_else(try_convert_config_to::<C>)
        .or_else(try_convert_config_to::<D>)
        .map_err(|cfg| panic!("Couldn't find matching type for filename `{}`", cfg.filename))
        .unwrap();

    job.run();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1467ced26a78de304f27dc0462eef986))